# How to achieve host and path based routing from AWS Application Load Balancers with virtual hosts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-cloudfront, nginx-ingress, aws-application-load-balancer

#### Background

I have **6** services `app1`, `app2`.. in a AWS EKS. They have their own ingresses
with following hosts (like virtual hosts).

- `app1.mylocaldomain.io`
- `app2.mylocaldomain.io`
- ..

(Their ingresses were baked into their Helm Charts)

There is also load balancer which both ingress use:
`alb-dns-name-kubernetes.com` (Created from nginx-ingress)

That means, When I can do curl with proper header, I get success response:

> `curl -H "Host: app1.mylocaldomain.io" alb-dns-name-kubernetes.com`

#### Desired behavior

I want to achieve path and host based routing with another extra Loadbalancer. (Which I will point to `app.domain.io` from **Route53**).If my New load balancer is `alb-dns-name-extra.com`, I want to achieve mix of path and host
based routing with my new domain `app.domain.io` like below:

- `app.domain.io/app1` --> `app1.mylocaldomain.io`
- `app.domain.io/app2` --> `app2.mylocaldomain.io`
  ...

Is there a way I can achieve this.

#### Restrictions

- Without creating extra ingress-resource in kubernetes.
- `*.mylocaldomain.io`, they are local host names, so simple redirect will not work.

Thanks

Comment: Not sure I get your question fully. Please check if one of the following help you resolve this.

AWS ALB weighted routing while Ingress rule present on same domain record alias
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61863837/aws-alb-weighted-routing-while-ingress-rule-present-on-same-domain-record-alias

Exposing kubernetes app using AWS Elastic LoadBalancer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54409889/exposing-kubernetes-app-using-aws-elastic-loadbalancer